# Login with curl and move to another page multiple times

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to log in to a website and redirect to pages that is declared in an array.
i logged in sucessfully and i'm getting the first url in the array.
but problem that i'm getting error when i'm looping through the code in the second time.

the code:

```
$url = 'https://url/signin';
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  $data = [
    "e_mail" => "email@",
    "password" => "123456"
  ];

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // allow redirections
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // we are making post request
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // COOKIEEjAR To save data for cookies created for login process
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // TRUE means dont just echo output the data instead we can store the request response in some variaable

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $urls_to_loop = array('url1', 'url2');

foreach ($urls_to_loop as $key => $url) {
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
          $exec = curl_exec($ch);

          // echo($exec);
          curl_close($ch);// close login CURL resource, and free up system resources

          $html = new simple_html_dom();
          $html->load($exec);
  $links = [];
  foreach($html->find('link') as $element){
    if($element->href[-1] === '4'){
      // check if url is not in the array
      if(!in_array($element->href, $links)){
        array_push($links, $element->href);
      }
    } 
  }

}//END foreach
```

and this is the error:

**Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\index.php on line 263**

**Warning: curl_exec(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\index.php on line 264**

**Warning: curl_close(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\index.php on line 267**

**Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\index.php on line 263**

Comment: The resource become invalid because of `curl_close($ch);`. Call it after all requests have been called (after foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the handler during the loop.

```
curl_close($ch);
```

Move that line to the end of your script.